# How to check is X509Certificate2 exportable or not

Tags: c#, .net, certificate

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(
    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);

X509Certificate2 cert = certificates[0];
```

Now we have X509Certificate2 instance. How to check exportable private key or not? (preferably without trying to export explicitly)

Comment: Export using what mechanism and parameters? The code only shows finding a certificate.

Comment: Does not matter. For example, using bouncy castle: `var key = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(GetCertificate(thumbprint).PrivateKey).Private;`. This code throw an exception if certificate is not exportable. Or in windows certificates mmc snap-in, you can select certificate, right click on it, all tasks, export. On appeared window private key radio can be disabled when certificate is not exportable. I want to detect it programmatically: exportable or not.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach I found here: [*How to determine whether an X509Certificate2 is exportable*](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com:443/forums/windowsdesktop/en-us/a319b2c8-dcd6-4225-b0cb-a66c1910b79e/how-to-determine-whether-an-x509certificate2-is-exportable)

> X509Certificate2.PrivateKey                Gets the AsymmetricAlgorithm object that represents the private key associated with a certificate.
>
> The RSACryptoServiceProvider class is a AsymmetricAlgorithm
>
> Then get the RSACryptoServiceProvider.CspKeyContainerInfo  which is a   CspKeyContainerInfo object that has a Exportable property that:   Gets a value indicating whether a key can be exported from a key container.

Update: works. So, if you use RSA certificates, it is acceptable approach.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/x509certificates/x509certificate.cs), the implementation of the `Export` method makes the following checks:

- That the `X509ContentType` parameter is `Cert`, `SerializedCert` or `Pfx`.
- When the content type is `Pfx` it makes a key container permission demand for both `Export` and `Open` permissions.

Beyond this, everything else happens via internal calls to the CLR, so it's much harder to say what demands are made of the caller. I can't observe a check in the source which tests for the exportable flag.

This is a scenario where I would suggest you attempt to perform the export and handle any exceptions as feedback; you cannot reasonably predict the outcome of the call with the information exposed by the certificate.

Comment: Ok. Now I implement as you say: try to export and catch exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this method:**

```
public static bool CheckCertificateIsExportable(X509Certificate2 certForCheck, X509ContentType certType)
    {
        try
        {
            certForCheck.Export(certType);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**How to use:**

```
if (CheckCertificateIsExportable(certForCheck, X509ContentType.Pkcs12))
        {
            // Do...
        }
```

Comment: It is try..catch approach. I use code like in you example in my app. Yes, it works. But it is not what I want exactly. I am surprised that no api exist to check it directly without this bicycle invention.